# Kirby diagram of Enriques surface (as the "(1/2) K3 surface")

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, 4-manifolds, kirby-calculus

Not to be confused with $E(1)\cong\mathbb{C}P^2\#9\overline{\mathbb{C}P^2}$, which is also known as a $\frac{1}{2}K3$ surface (in the sense that removing a neighbourhood of a regular torus fiber in $E(1)$ and then gluing two copies of this along their $T^3$ boundary gives $K3$). The Enriques surface $X$ has $\pi_1(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and its double cover is the $K3$ surface.

I would like to produce a Kirby/handle diagram of the Enriques surface, and whilst I haven't been able to find one in the literature, there is the following diagram,

[image: pictured here]

(originally due to Kondo I believe, though taken here from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.3506.pdf)) representing a configuration of singular fibers in $X$ (specifically, the set of 9 line segments to the left representing an $I_9$-singular fiber, $F$ a nodal fiber, and $S_1, S_2$ a pair of bisections). I think it should be possible to recover/construct a Kirby diagram from this diagram, since for example there are well known tables translating between these singular fibers and Kirby/link diagrams e.g. [in this book](https://bookstore.ams.org/memo-62-350/), or the following image

[image: here]

Where I am stuck, is how $S_1$ and $S_2$ should intersect/link the associated spheres in the $I_9$ and node fibers, as well as what their associated framings should be.

So in summary:

1. Is the "curve configuration" picture given here sufficient to reconstruct a handle diagram? If so, how do I draw the $S_1$ and $S_2$ curves correctly in such a diagram, and what should their framings be?
2. If not, does anyone know of either a reference to an existing handle diagram, or otherwise how one might go about constructing one?